# How to test event listeners using QUnit

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, qunit

I'm using pure Javascript (no JQuery) and I'm trying to get QUnit to test my function that is only invoked via an event, i.e. it's an event listener.

So the function I wish to test is of the form:

```
(function() {
   function the_one_i_want_to_test() {
      // do stuff
   }

   window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      var some_element = ...;
      some_element.addEventListener('click', the_one_i_want_to_test);
   });
})();
```

I know I could expose the function to test it, but it is only ever used as an event listener and I don't want to pollute the global namespace.

That's why I am trying to kill two birds with one stone by manually triggering a "click" event and then checking for desired effects (in my tests).

The problem is that the event handler doesn't seem to be executing at all, either because QUnit doesn't wait for it before performing the effects checks, or for some other reason.

So my QUnit test code looks like this:

```
QUnit.test('test function', function(assert) {             
   var some_element = ...;
   var event = document.createEvent('Event');
   event.initEvent('click', true, true);
   some_element.dispatchEvent(event);

   assert.ok(...assert one or more effects of running "the_one_i_want_to_test"...);
});
```

I have tried including JQuery just for the tests to use ".trigger()", but that doesn't seem to help.

The event listener executes fine/normally on the production page, just not in the tests.

Any ideas on why the event listener doesn't seem to be running?

Comment: You should probably use an async construct, look [here](https://api.qunitjs.com/async/)

Comment: I looked into that, but I don't understand how it works and hence how to it apply it to my use case. Could you perhaps provide an example for my scenario? More specifically, in the example you linked, why is done() placed after the assert?

Comment: The way async test usually work (as it does with QUnit) is that you use some method to indicate to the test framework the current test is complete. In QUnit you do that by calling `assert.async()` to indicate QUnit *should* wait for a call to the returned function (`done()`)

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say, in that most likely the problem is caused by the test framework not knowing to wait for the event listener to finish executing, but I don't understand the example on the QUnit page you linked and how it achieves that.

Comment: Wait a minute... Are you saying the event isn't handled at all, or that the effects aren't "visible" to your code? You could try to surround your `assert.ok` call with a `setTimeout` the same in the documentation (use a 3 seconds timeout just to be sure)

Comment: The handler doesn't seem to be executing at all, even when I tried what you just suggested.

Comment: set some breakpoints inside your test AND code to see what parts are not working. That's the only logical next step

Comment: Thanks Amit, will post my solution.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, event handlers are not executed immediately when the event is raised. They are queued up on a list, and execute after the current code block is done.  By that time, the test is over.

You have to use the setTimeout trick to queue up your validation code so that it executes after the handler.  When the delay is 0 (or unspecified), the code will be queued for execution as soon as possible, meaning right after the event handler gets a chance to run.

As Amit says, you also need to use the `assert.async()` method to get a `done()` function that you'll call after your assertions. This makes `QUnit.test` wait until you invoke it before moving on to the next test.

Try something like this:

```
QUnit.test('test function', function(assert) {             
   var some_element = ...;
   var event = document.createEvent('Event');
   event.initEvent('click', true, true);
   some_element.dispatchEvent(event);

   var done = assert.async();
   setTimeout(function() {
        assert.ok(...assert one or more effects of running "the_one_i_want_to_test"...);
        done();
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the code you wish to test is actually included in your web page.

I have been running in a headless environment and didn't get any runtime errors (apart from the failed assertions). With the help of @Amit (to bring me to my senses), I tried running the tests in a browser and discovered the code was not even being included in the page.