# How to unit test an A-Frame component with Qunit?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit, aframe

Let's imagine we have a basic A-Frame component:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('scale-on-mouseenter', {
    schema: {
        to: {
            default: '2 2 2'
        }
    },
    init: function () {
        this.el.addEventListener('mouseneter', function () {
            this.setAttribute('scale', data.to);
        });
    }
});
```

And I want to test through QUnit. How to test if this component creates the `scale` attribute?

Should I create a "testing A-Scene" for this purpose and verify the DOM? Or is there a more "unit" way to test?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916358/writing-test-specs-for-a-frame help?

Comment: Yes, it helps a lot. Thank you. I write an answer (but I'm still not sure my approach is good for the EventListener part. Feel free to write your own answer, and I accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem presented here is divided in two parts.

- Testing a component
- Testing an EventListener

### Testing a component

The link provided by ngokevin gives a solution. More especially, looking at existing tests shows that we need to create a testing `a-scene`
https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/tests/components/scale.test.js

That's not really a unitary test, but hey, I do not want to mock all the A-Frame library!

Let's start with a more basic code to test, without an `EventListener`.

```
// Set a scale factor to 2 2 2
AFrame.registerComponent('big', {
    init: function () {
        this.el.setAttribute('scale', '2 2 2');
    }
});
```

The associated test needs to create a testing `a-scene`. We can use `QUnit.module` for that.

```
QUnit.module('Component testing', {
    before: function () {
        var scene = document.createElement('a-scene');
        document.querySelector('#qunit-fixture').appendChild(scene);
    },
    after: function () {
        var scene = document.querySelector('#qunit-fixture > a-scene'); 
        scene.parentNode.removeChild(scene);
    }
});
```

And now, we can test the component by creating an `a-entity`, and see if the attribute is created when the component is added to the tag. We just have to wait for the component to be loaded. Otherwise, the assert is made before the component is loaded, and will eventually fail.

```
QUnit.test('Big add scale to 2 2 2', function (assert) {
    // Create the entity to test
    var entity = document.createElement('a-entity');
    entity.setAttribute('big', '');

    // Add it to the testing a-scene
    var scene = document.querySelector('#qunit-fixture > a-scene');
    scene.appendChild(entity);

    // Wait for the component to be loaded
    var done = assert.async()
    entity.addEventListener('loaded', function () {
        // Actual test
        assert.deepEqual(
            entity.getAttribute('scale'), 
            {'x': 2, 'y': 2, 'z': 2});
        done();
    });
});
```

### Testing an EventListener

The original problem involved an `EventListener`. As a reminding purpose, this was the code to test.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('scale-on-mouseenter', {
    schema: {
        to: {
            default: '2 2 2'
        }
    },
    init: function () {
        this.el.addEventListener('mouseneter', function () {
            this.setAttribute('scale', data.to);
        });
    }
});
```

Testing this needs another trick. One solution is to create a named function, then add this function as handler in the `EventListener` as described [here](http://webcloud.se/best-practice-testing-javascript-event-handlers/). The tests will test the named function alone, but not the `addEventListener` part.

A second solution is to use the `setTimeout` trick as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32315954/5512755)
. The final test will use the previous work to test the component, then dispatch an `Event`, then use the `assert` part inside a `setTimeout` to queue the test. A timeout of 0 works very well.

```
QUnit.test('scale-on-mouseenter add eventlistener', function (assert) {
    // Create the entity to test
    var entity = document.createElement('a-entity');
    entity.setAttribute('scale-on-mouseenter', '');

    // Add it to the testing a-scene
    var scene = document.querySelector('#qunit-fixture > a-scene');
    scene.appendChild(entity);

    // Wait for the component to be loaded
    var done = assert.async()
    entity.addEventListener('loaded', function () {
        // Dispatch the event
        entity.dispatchEvent(new Event("mouseenter"));
        // Queue the test with a timeout of 0
        setTimeout(function () {
            // Actual test
            assert.deepEqual(
                entity.getAttribute('scale'), 
                {'x': 2, 'y': 2, 'z': 2});
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice. The Karma + Mocha suite is fully capable of testing event listeners. If you check the tests, there are tons of `addEventListener`s and `el.emit`s. Also you can emit event using `entity.emit`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm stuck with QUnit, but it looks like Karma is available for QUnit too. Anyway, I do not have a lot of EventListeners to test.